# add a new dialog with new layout on the currently running activity without making changes to the layout file of currently running activity

Tags: android, android-layout

how can I add a new dialog with new layout on the currently running activity without making changes to the layout file of currently running activity. I cannot add a new activity as the old activity should remain active while the new dialog is displayed.

Comment: Create a `Dialog` and set a `View` on it? Not really sure where your problem is

Comment: I am a noob and don't know much. Thank you for your comment. I will try to google about the things you mentioned :)

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111.    Refer this site it will help you

Comment: @ArunAntoney is there a way to not blur the background when the dialog comes. Currently my background gets blur when the dialog comes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small snippet to get started on creating a `Dialog` and applying a layout file to it.

```
    // create an instance of Dialog
    Dialog dialog= new Dialog(c, R.style.CustDialog);  

    //inflate a layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);

    // set the layout for the Dialog
    dialog.setContentView(root);
```

If you read the [Dialog Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it gives the different methods you can use.

**Note the docs say**

> The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly. Instead, use one of the following subclasses:

So for this reason you may want to look at [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) which you can find plenty of examples of on SO or the Google.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android) gives an example of creating a custom `Dialog` class.

Comment: yeah I got it working thank you :)
Earlier I had tried to google but as I have just started android I didn't even knew what to google and had no time to start learning android from scratch

Comment: In http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/ the background gets blur when the dialog comes, is there a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: I don't know off-hand but typically that's what you want so the `Dialog` sticks out. You might try [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). I use that and the `Activity` doesn't dim

Comment: PopUpWindow is exactly what I needed. Thank You!